# javascript how to open a exe on server

Tags: javascript, exe

im adding some functionality´s on me site and i would like to open some exe´s i have made using vb2010 ,the exe will me on my local server but the site will be hosted in a server some were in the world .

to execute the exe i just need to add  boton on the site whit the path to the location of the file on my server? like

```
  C:\folder\folder\myfile.exe
```

or there other more easy way to do this ?

thnx for any help

Comment: Thats not possible as far as I know....allowing javascript to run exe files will create major security problems and  so that thing is not implemented..

Comment: To execute an .exe file you'll need *server side code* not javascript. You may add a button to your webpage that will trigger the execution of an .exe. But the execution of the .exe file needs to be started from code that *runs on your server*. That is either in your code behind if you are using ASP.NET or in your controller if you're using MVC or in a webservice.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Put it this way, if you had such a button, what's to stop me passing `rm /s/q C:` and watching your entire hard drive disappear?

Instead, have a form with a `<select>` element that lists the programs you want to run as keys, such as `myfile`, then submit that to the server. Then have the server verify that the key is allowed, and if so run the corresponding program.

Answer (score 0):

This is not possible directly, because it is not safe at all.
You have to do it on the serverside. Call a webservice function on the webserver that can make a call to the exe file.

Reference [enter link description here](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/)

Comment: This is hard to explain without knowing what kind of application you are working on. Is it ASP.NET, PHP etc?

Comment: If you are using ASP.NET: [link](http://encosia.com/using-jquery-to-directly-call-aspnet-ajax-page-methods/)
If you are using PHP: [link](http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/opensource/library/os-php-jquery-ajax/)

How to handle it on the server is just plain .NET code for example: [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1971130/run-a-server-side-exe-from-asp-beginner). But if you are not sure that you can't connect to the other server by a network, this other server with the exe file should expose some webservice or something else too.

Answer (score 0):

From your question I understand the web server and the exe are in two different networks. I assume both the servers don't have access to each other. If that is the case, you cannot execute the exe when the button is clicked on the page.

If the exe is on the client, then where the page is displaying then also you would not be allowed to execute it due to security sandbox model.

Comment: yes as far i know threes 2 different servers not connected to each other, the server were the site its hosted and the server were the site db is. but i have to ask to my boss to be 100% correct on what im saying

Comment: If its a DB server, then there will be connectivity between those two. But, your question is not clear. Kindly make the question meaningful. From where is javascript related to DB server?